# How do I reload/refresh app.config?

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, config

I want to read the `app.config` value, show it in a message box, change the value using an external text editor, and finally show the updated value.

I tried using the following code:

```cs
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name);
    MessageBox.Show(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TheValue"]);
}
```

But it doesn't work. It shows the old value (before changing in external text editor).
Any suggestions?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
  <add key="TheValue" value="abc"/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 13):

It may help you

try to save configuration like this

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.AppSettings.Settings["KeyName"].Value = "NewValue";
config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

and then fetch it like this

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Comment: The key statement here is `config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using the following code:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings = config.AppSettings.Settings;            
// update SaveBeforeExit
settings["TheValue"].Value = "WXYZ";
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

MessageBox.Show(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TheValue"]);
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question until it explains what the code does and why it solves his problem.

Answer (score 2):

This should reload the app.config file from disk:

```
var appSettings = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location).AppSettings;
MessageBox.Show(appSettings.Settings["TheValue"].Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is all you really need.

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
MessageBox.Show(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TheValue"]);
```

Likely the problem that you're having is that you're modifying the wrong App.config file. I did this myself and felt silly. If you're using the IDE to test your code, change the YourAppName.vshost.exe.config file in your bin directory instead. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the application's property settings (Properties.Settings.Default.Xxxx)
you can use

Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
var x = Properties.Settings.Default.Xxxx; // x will get new value from config